# AutoCompletion with the editor

Tags: editor, autocomplete

I find that the autocompletion capability with the programming editor is a mixed blessing.  Sometimes it anticipates correctly, or, when multiple choices might come from what is already typed, it advances to the next logical point, and typing the next expected letter moves it in the right direction.  Reaaly sweet when it works right.

However, it often creates the wrong key word and advances all the way to the end, forcing a backspacing process that certainly doesn't add to the coding efficiency.  Is there any way to back space word-by-word, or return the cursor to the point from which it jumped forward?  That would certainly help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

In most editors, it backspaces a logical word, using camelCase or under_score notation.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to jump the cursor around a word a time.

Answer (score 0):

To backspace word by word try [Ctrl] + [Backspace]

You can also use [Ctrl] + arrows, [Ctrl] + [Shift] + arrows to respectively move and select word by word

Answer (score 0):

As Utaal mentioned, you can use Control+Backspace. Also, in most editors with autocomplete you can hit "escape" before autocomplete has actually selected an entry to cancel it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If the auto complete is implemented correctly, hitting the editors *undo key* should undo the errant auto complete.